# 'stop' & 'start' is not a member of System.Windows.Forms.Timer vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to start and stop a timer and it keeps telling me that they are both not a member of System.Windows.Forms.Timer
 Below is my code. I used this in a different windows project and it works fine, don't know if I have to initialize it differently in this project.

```
Private Sub InitializeComponent()
            Me.timer = New System.Windows.Forms.Timer
End Sub 


Private Sub timer_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles timer.Tick
            counter -= 1
            If counter = 0 Then
                timer.Stop()
                lblPrice.Text = "$0.00"
                lblBarcode.Text = "Place Item Near Scanner"
                lblName.Text = ""
                lblID.Text = ""
                lblUnit.Text = "Price Checker"
                counter = 8
            End If
End Sub
 Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
timer = New System.Windows.Forms.Timer
AddHandler timer.Tick, AddressOf Me.timer_Tick
timer.Interval = 1000
timer.Start()
End Sub
```

Comment: Why have you created a `Timer` in the designer and then keep creating a new one every time you click that `Button`?

Comment: Is `timer` a Component you dropped onto the Form's Designer from the ToolBox? You're not only new-ing it on each Button.Click, you're also adding a new handler to the Tick event each time. If it's a Field you defined, see that the Field type is not `Object` and add the handler once in the Form's Constructor. What is this `Private Sub InitializeComponent()`? What is it doing there? Is this a Form or something else?